# How to transpile using typescript, only specific files?

Tags: typescript

So here is my plan. I want to build an application using Typescript for Windows and Mac. However, as I'm gonna transpiling the Typeascript code to Javascript code, I want to achieve some feature if possible. I want to get only Windows code when I want, and only Mac code when I want.

They way I want to do it, or at-least trying, is to use the `exclude` in tsconfig.json.

Let's take simple example.
In the root project I would have `src` folder. Inside, I would have `code.ts` file.
Also: `code.darwin.ts` and `code.windows.ts` files.

code.darwin.ts:

```
const Logger = () => {
    console.log('DARWIN');
}

export default Logger;
```

code.windows.ts:

```
const Logger = () => {
    console.log('WINDOWS');
}

export default Logger;
```

code.ts:

```
import Logger from './code.darwin';
import Logger from './code.windows';

Logger();
```

In this example, if I want only mac code I'd use tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {

    "target": "ES2017",                                /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017', 'ES2018', 'ES2019', 'ES2020', or 'ESNEXT'. */
    "module": "commonjs",                           /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', 'es2020', or 'ESNext'. */
    "outDir": "./dist",                        /* Redirect output structure to the directory. */
    "rootDir": "./src",                       /* Specify the root directory of input files. Use to control the output directory structure with --outDir. */
    "strict": true,                                 /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
    "alwaysStrict": true,                        /* Parse in strict mode and emit "use strict" for each source file. */
    "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types"],                             /* List of folders to include type definitions from. */
    "esModuleInterop": true,                        /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */
    "skipLibCheck": true,                           /* Skip type checking of declaration files. */
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true        /* Disallow inconsistently-cased references to the same file. */
  },
  "exclude": ["**/*.windows.ts"],
}
```

But yet, I have ts clash error in `code.ts` because I import same thing from 2 files. Any idea how to resolve it?

**The way I do it is not a must. I'm open to other suggestions using Typescript. The most important thing is that I'll be able to get only 1 OS platform code finally.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use dynamic import feature of Typescript.
You should use `process.platform` in order to get it work.

Edit your code.ts file to:

```
import(`./code.${process.platform}`).then((logger) => {
    logger();
});
```

Keep all other files the same.

Note the import expression. Adjust it to your needs.